# "The meaning of words depends solely on mental concepts inside the human brain"

Tags: terminology

What does "the meaning of words depends solely on mental concepts inside the human brain" illustrate?

An internalist or externalist position ? Brief reason why.

Thanks !

Comment: What is that quote from? Is this a homework question?

Comment: It illustrates the fact that meaning depends on the person who is interpreting the word. For example the word "homework" may have a different meaning for a teacher and for a student.

Answer (score -1):

Just like it is not possible to define life, soul, so is the question. One theory could be dividing the world into living beings and non living beings. But delving on such themes will mean we are off topic.

Comment: I am a literate native English speaker and I find it difficult to determine what this answer means.  Please clarify.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann When we talk about mental concepts, things become subjective. We have restricted science to tangible things like 2+2=4. The dilemma with linguistics study I guess is we are unable to come to terms how a 3-year-old child can frame sentences, learns to speak so many words almost effortlessly. To see and feel is part of us as living beings and human beings are in a unique position to leverage words (ability to speak and understand) which is dormant or less developed in other species. But delving on such issues might be labeled unscientific, off topic here.

Comment: I agree with your last sentence.